# i am getting an error of 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__' when i run the following code in Boa constructor GUI base python program

Tags: python, file, object, attributes

When I run the following code in Boa constructor GUI base python program.

```
 def OnGraphitButton(self, event):
        VDWAALS=[]
        file=open("/home/fareeha/Desktop/GraphMDresearch_paper/Sourcecodes/b.csv",'r')
        line=file.readlines()
        parts = file[-1].split(",")[0]
        frame_number = parts
        for a in line:
         if 'DELTA Energy Terms' in a:
             tick=2
             print ("The frame is: ", frame_number, re.findall("\d+", Bframe_number))
             while tick<int(frame_number)+1:
               print a, "##", frame_number,tick   
               VDWAALS.append(line[line.index(a)+tick].split(',')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading file's contents into `line` which becomes a list of strings, but then you attempt to retrieve the last line from `file` object instead of `line`, thus causing the error.

Code with this bug fixed would look like:

```
def OnGraphitButton(self, event):
    VDWAALS=[]
    file=open("/home/fareeha/Desktop/GraphMDresearch_paper/Sourcecodes/b.csv",'r')
    line=file.readlines()
    parts = line[-1].split(",")[0] # <<< FIXED LINE
    frame_number = parts
    for a in line:
        if 'DELTA Energy Terms' in a:
            tick=2
            print ("The frame is: ", frame_number, re.findall("\d+", Bframe_number))
            while tick<int(frame_number)+1:
                print a, "##", frame_number,tick
                VDWAALS.append(line[line.index(a)+tick].split(',')[1])
```

Please make sure to post your actual error tracebacks in the future instead of trying to describe what they say. Only the most trivial mistakes can be easily detected in another's code without a related traceback.